# Problems creating an animated gif in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, gif

I am trying to create an animated gif from an array of 4 `UIImage` elements in Swift but currently it only saves the first frame.

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: photosDirectory)?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename())

if let url = url {
    let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]
    let gifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: 0.125]]
    let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeGIF, photos.count, nil)

    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties)

    for photo in photos {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, photo.CGImage, gifProperties)
    }

    return CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
}
else {
    return false
}
```

`photos` is the array of `UIImages`
`filename()` just returns a string like `20150805.gif`

It returns true but only the first frame is in the gif

Answer (score 2):

kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime 
should be in float not double.

try setting 0.125f instead of 0.125

Comment: Irrelevant; it's turned into an `NSNumber` so there's no practical difference.

Comment: Wow, I take it back. On iOS 8.2, it *does* matter! I don't know how ImageIO managed to possibly do that. On iOS 8.3 and later, a `Double` is perfectly fine.