# How to save NSData as gif to Album

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, gif

I use function here https://gist.github.com/westerlund/eae8ec71cdac88be7c3a
to create a gif file of an array of images, but the return type is `NSData`. 
How can I use this data and save it to album?

I have tried `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`. It's not work, it only saved the first image of the image array. I have googled a function named `writeimagedatatosavedphotosalbum`, but it's already been deprecated in iOS9.
So what's the latest way the save a `.gif` file to album?

Comment: did you try
     `[NSData* writeTofile:(NSString*) path atomically:BOOL]`

Comment: Are animated GIFs actually supported in the photo album? Have you tried saving such an image using the usual UIs?

Comment: The same question as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845981/problems-creating-an-animated-gif-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

**First Get a file URL**

```
guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myGifFile.gif")
```

**Write gifData to File URL**

```
try? gifData.write(to: fileURL)
```

**Save the file from URL to Album**

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges ({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL: fileURL)
}) { saved, error in
    if saved {
        print("Your image was successfully saved")
    }
}
```